# Listening for changes in a document and that document's subcollection

Tags: angular, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have `Room` object that has some properties like `Title` and `Description`.  It also has a property called `Players` which is a string array of users uids.

In Firestore, I've set `Players` as a subcollection of my `Room` document.

I get `Room` data by using this:

```
 getRooms(): Observable<Room[]> {
    return this._db.collection<Room>('rooms').valueChanges();
  }();
```

When I subscribe to this, it of curse, does not know if something happened in the `Players` subcollection.

Is there a way I can add some code to also listen for the changes in the `Players` subcollection.

Ideally, I would like to subscribe once and listen for changes in either my Rooms/Room Document or in my Rooms/Room/Players subcollection.

Comment: maybe you are looking for a way to subscribe multiple observables?

Comment: Yes, looks like I will have to do that.  Initially, I had `Players` be a `Room` property but I've changed my approach and made it a subcollection so now I have to deal with this hurdle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore client libraries don't offer this feature.  You will have to also have to create a collection reference to each subcollection and add a listener to each one of those.  It could be the same listener object for each one, but there is no avoiding referencing each subcollection by name.

Comment: Thank you, that is all I needed. It is working now.  Little more cumbersome compared to if `Room` had a `Players` property (rather then a subcollection) but I found that certain Firestore rules were easier to implement with `Players` being a subcollection

Comment: Yes, there is always a tradeoff there, but fortunately, there is no real change in performance either way.